# Array printing strange values after printing four correct values in c language

Tags: c

am trying to print first two digit from a series of an integer value. but after selecting each of the values and storing them in an array. when i try to print the values the array tend to only store correctly the first four value and afterwards the rest of the value becomes strange. this is my code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    long credit = 24681482846434;
    int mid_length = (14 / 2);  // length of array
    int arr[mid_length];
    int d = 100;
    int count = 1;
    //loop to get the first second numbers
    for (int i = mid_length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        arr[i] = (credit % d) / (d / 10);
        d = d * 100;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        count++;
    }
}
```

this the output:

```
3
6
8
8
7
0
9
credit/ $
```

Comment: What OS? On windows long is 32 bit

Comment: You may find it beneficial to include `<stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t`.

Comment: `d` is overflowing.  Needs a 64-bit type.

Comment: Show actual vs. desired output as well.

Comment: If you expect 64-bit number ranges, always use long long(or even unsigned long long), because long long is guaranteed to be minimum 64-bit, whereas long is not guaranteed to be always 64-bit. 'd' is definitely overflowing, so you better change it to long long.

Comment: A "number" (such as card or phone) isn't necessarily an integer. So consider working with `char credit[] = "24681482846434";`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen am on mac

Comment: Try printing `credit`. You may need: `uint64_t credit = 24681482846434LL;`

Comment: @WeatherVane i intend performing some mathematical computation on the number and that wont work with a char type

Comment: @StanleyOmeje, did you read my comment? Just change the type of `d` to long(long is 64 bit on your system obviously), because it is overflowing at the moment, and it will be fixed.

Comment: @малинчекуров u mean using long long for credit like: long long credit = 24681482846434

Comment: @малинчекуров if i increase the number of the card to 16 digit, the array ends up holding only 7 of the selected number instead of 8 values.. do u have any idea on how i can go about it

Comment: @StanleyOmeje becase your array can store only 7 digits. Look at your array size, it is 14/2(and your original credit number is 14 digits). If you need to increase the credit number, you need to increase the array as well. For 16 digits, the array size needs to be at least 16/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an arithmetic overflow in `d = d * 100` at the 5th iteration when `d` is `100000000` and the multiplication exceeds the range of type `int`.  Changing the type to `long` or `long long` will fix this issue.

Type `long` probably has 64 bits on your machine, but for portability, you should use `long long` or `unsigned long long` for `credit` and `d`.

The code might be somewhat easier to follow with a slightly different method where you divide the number instead of multiplying the divisor.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long credit = 24681482846434;
    int mid_length = (14 + 1) / 2;  // length of array
    int arr[mid_length];
    //loop to get the first digit of digit pairs
    long long temp = credit;
    for (int i = mid_length; i --> 0;) {
        int pair = temp % 100;
        temp /= 100;
        arr[i] = pair / 10;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's most likely happening is you're not using a sufficiently large integer type for `credit`.  While, on some systems, `long` is big enough to hold 63-bit integers (64-bit if `unsigned`), the C standard only requires that it be big enough to hold 31-bit integers (32-bit if `unsigned`).  The number you're trying to store into `credit` is a 45-bit integer which is probably too big and, therefore, is being truncated down to a smaller number.

If that's the issue, you'd need to switch to a larger integer type.  `long long` is required to be big enough.  You can also include stdint.h and explicitly use a 64-bit integer type: `uint64_t`.